# Question concerning continuity of some linear map

Tags: functional-analysis

So here is my question,

I wanted to prove that the canonical embedding of $\ell^p(\mathbb N,\mathbb C)$ in $c_0:=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb C:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0\}$ is continuous. Since the embedding is linear I wanted to show that the map is bounded but I failed to find a proper bound. I managed to prove the continuity with classical methods then but I am still wondering how one can show that the embedding is actually bounded?

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can argue that $\lVert x\rVert_{\infty} \le \lVert x\rVert_p$.

Comment: Think about proving Cameron's hint in the case of a positive decreasing sequence.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Does this alway hold or can you tell me where my mistake is? I thought about the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}:=(\frac{1}{2},0,0,...)$. Then $||x_n||_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$ but $||x_n||_p=\frac{1}{2^p}$ hence $||x_n||_p\leq||x_n||_{\infty}$.

Comment: You forgot to take $p$th root.

Comment: Yeah the error is that (in this case) $\lVert x\rVert = \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p + 0^p +\cdots\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. You should get a norm of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ahhh i totally forgot about the exponent! thanks! That cleans up my mess :D